# Persistent subprocess session

Tags: python, subprocess, confluent-cloud

I'm having trouble thinking of the best way to approach this, but I want to login to confluent cloud from Python.

I have a function which retrieves the user/pass to log into Confluent, I'd then like a function to login, and then a function to do what I want with the cluster..

```
def login():
    email, password = get_secret()
    env_vars = os.environ.copy()
    env_vars["CONFLUENT_CLOUD_EMAIL"] = email
    env_vars["CONFLUENT_CLOUD_PASSWORD"] = password

    subprocess.run("confluent login", shell=True, env=env_vars)
    subprocess.run("confluent cluster list", shell=True)
```

I'm testing by just using `subprocess.run()` within the same function, and of course.. the second command fails, saying not logged in! Because when the first subprocess run closes, it ends the session.

I've tinkered with having `Popen` outside of the functions, something like;

```
p = subprocess.Popen("/bin/sh", env=env_vars, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE
```

Then inside the relevant function just using something like `p.stdin.write("command")`, but that doesn't work either.

I'm scratching my head as to the best way to achieve this.

Comment: `pexpect` maybe? https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: The issue isn't with the interactive login. The environment variables take care of the user/pass. It's just that when the next process is spawned, it no longer knows it's logged in. Presumably because there's a session which is only valid while that particular shell is open.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I have been doing, its one time login that will save your credentials in $HOME/.netrc, then you shell out `confluent` how you want.

```
confluent login --no-browser --prompt --save
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for doing it this way was because the Terraform provider for confluent cloud didn't have a resource to create cluster api-keys.

The provider has been updated in the last 48 hours, and now has the resource. So I no longer have a need for this. Updating here in case anyone else needs to know the provider is updated..